# Preparing SQL Data for a CDF Plot

Tags: sql, presto, looker, amazon-athena

i have the following SQL that I would like to use to plot cumulative distribution plot but i can't seem to get the data right.

Sample Data:

| token_Length | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6436 |
| 2 | 7489 |
| 3 | 3724 |
| 4 | 2440 |
| 5 | 667 |
| 6 | 396 |
| 7 | 264 |
| 8 | 215 |
| 9 | 117 |
| 10 | 90 |
| 11 | 61 |
| 12 | 29 |
| 13 | 69 |
| 15 | 40 |
| 18 | 45 |

How do i prepare this data to create a CDF plot in looker?

So that it looks like

| token_Length | Frequency | cume_dist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6436 | 0.291459107 |
| 2 | 7489 | 0.630604112 |
| 3 | 3724 | 0.799248256 |
| 4 | 2440 | 0.909745494 |
| 5 | 667 | 0.939951091 |
| 6 | 396 | 0.95788425 |
| 7 | 264 | 0.969839688 |
| 8 | 215 | 0.979576125 |
| 9 | 117 | 0.984874558 |
| 10 | 90 | 0.988950276 |
| 11 | 61 | 0.991712707 |
| 12 | 29 | 0.993025994 |
| 13 | 69 | 0.996150711 |
| 15 | 40 | 0.997962141 |
| 18 | 45 | 1 |

I have tried a measure as follows:

```
 measure: cume_dist {
    type: number
    sql:  cume_dist() over (order by ${token_length} ASC);;
  }
```

This generates SQL as:

```
SELECT
     token_length,
    COUNT(*) AS "count",
    cume_dist() over (order by (token_length) ASC) AS "cume_dist"
FROM string_facts
```

Comment: Can you please add sample data and desired output?

Comment: amended the question!

Comment: Your sample data does not have strings

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I can't share that data. I have provided the token length in the table as an example.

Comment: and the sql is to show an example of how it is generated.

Comment: I have amended the sql to remove the strings.

Comment: Without data - your SQL query looks fine.

Comment: Thanks, i thought it looked ok. Results seemed strange and not what i expected in my real data.